# The behavior of vectors that cannot be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors for the recursive equation $x_{k+1}=Ax_k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I have a question regarding the sequence of vectors given by
$x_{k+1}=Ax_k, \quad k=0,1,2,...$
with initial vector $x_0$. If the initial condition can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $A$, then the long-term behavior can be understood quite easily since
$x_k=A^k x_0=A^k(c_1v_1+...+c_pv_p)=c_1\lambda_1^k v_1 + ... + c_p \lambda_p^k v_p$
From this equation we can look at the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue in absolute value to understand how the system will evolve as $k$ increases. My question concerns the nature of the system if the initial condition cannot be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors (A is not diagonalizable). In this case how would we expect the system to evolve? Would it converge to something that can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors or does something entirely different happen, if it can even be determined?

Comment: I don't know about the general behaviour, but one example is if $A$ is a rotation matrix. Then the sequence will just be cycling and won't converge to any single direction.

Comment: If a matrix $J$  is in Jordan normal form  $J = D  + N,$   where $D$  and $N$   commute, with $D$ diagonal and $N$  nilpotent, we can find $J^k = (D+N)^k$  which can be done with binomial coefficients. Therefore, given some $A,$   we construct $P$  with $J=   P^{-1}  A P $  in Jordan form and $A = PJ P^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach to the problem that's very similar to that outlined in Will Jagy's comment.

You can always express the initial vector as a linear combination of [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).  A generalized eigenvector is a non zero vector $\ v\ $ such that $\ (A-\lambda I)^nv=0\ $ for some eigenvalue $\ \lambda\ $ and natural number $\ n\ $.  For each eigenvalue $\ \lambda\ $ there exists one or more sequences of linearly independent generalised eigenvectors $\ w_0, w_1,\dots, w_r\ $ such that

- $\ w_0\ $ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ \lambda\ $;
- $\ (A-\lambda I)w_i=w_{i-1}\ $ for $\ i=1,2,\dots, r\ $; and
- $\ w_r\not\in\text{ colspace}(A-\lambda I)\ $.

It's not difficult to show by double induction on $\ i\ $ and $\ n\ $ that
$$
A^nw_i=\sum_{j=0}^i\lambda^{n-j}{n\choose j}w_{i-j}\ .
$$
Thus, if $\ x_0=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_pv_p\ $ with $\ c_i\ne0\ $ and $\ v_i\ $ now generalised eigenvectors, then the asymptotic behaviour of $\ A^nx_0\ $ will still be determined by looking at the generalised eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue with the largest magnitide. If there's a sequence $\ w_0, w_1,\dots, w_r\ $ of generalised eigenvectors  of the form described above corresponding to that eigenvalue, the dominating term will be $\ \lambda^{n-r}{n\choose r}w_0\ $.

If $\ v_1,v_2,\dots,v_q\ $ is a basis of generalised eigenvectors of the form described above, arranged in an appropriate order, then the matrix of the linear transformation $\ x\mapsto Ax\ $ with respect to that basis is a Jordan normal form of $\ A\ $:
$$
J=P^{-1}AP\ ,
$$
where $\ P\ $ is the matrix with columns $\ v_1,v_2,\dots, v_q\ $. You then have
$$
A^nx_0=PJ^nP^{-1}x_0\ ,
$$
and this is probably the most straightforward way of tackling the problem.